# How to capture more of the path with dynamic route matching?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

A link is fetched from the database, e.g. `/app/profile`.

A single component (`master/index.vue`) should render any path following the app's address (`http://example.com/`).

I have the following router configuration:

```
{
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('@/components/Layout.vue'),
    children: [
        {
            path: ':id',
            component: () => import('@/components/pages/master/index.vue')
        }
    ]
}
```

… but this is not working as expected. It only accepts one param after `example.com`. How do I make it work dynamically so that it accepts multiple params, e.g. `/app/profile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an asterisk to match *anything*, for example:

```js
path: '*',
```

if you know the base path will be fixed, you can narrow the match to e.g. `/*`, `/app*`.

see the [vue-router docs on dynamic matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route), under the *catch all* section.